I'm using logstash to put in a csv file and I'm getting _csvparsefailure
I'm using logstash to put in a csv file and I'm getting _csvparsefailure. I don't know why.
Below is the content of my conf file.
input {
  file {
    path => "c:/s/test.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [ "message", "\r", "" ]
  }
  csv {
    separator => ","
    quote_char => "\""
    columns => ["t", "i", "c", "d", "u", "u2", "p", "b", "m", "m2"]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    cloud_id => "*" 
    api_key => "*"
    index => "lea"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}

Here is my sample data
"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"
"a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a10"

Below is my result.
{
  "@timestamp" => 2024-04-23T07:48:54.097522500Z,
  "log" => {
    "file" => {
      "path" => "c:/s/test.csv"
    }
  },
  "tags" => [
    [0] "_csvparsefailure"
  ],
  "message" => "\"a1\",\"a2\",\"a3\",\"a4\",\"a5\",\"a6\",\"a7\",\"a8\",\"a9\",\"a10\"",
  "event" => {
    "original" => "\"a1\",\"a2\",\"a3\",\"a4\",\"a5\",\"a6\",\"a7\",\"a8\",\"a9\",\"a10\""
  },
  "@version" => "1",
  "host" => {
    "name" => "au"
  }
}

How can I parse it correctly without errors?
I tried deleting the "", and I tried removing the carriage return.
Thank you.

quote_char => "\""

With the default configuration that does not work the way you want it to work. You could use quote_char => '"'. Setting config.support_escapes in logstash.yml is another option. There are many issues on github that discuss how escaping quotes works in the logstash configuration compiler. You could start here and follow links from there to get more background.
